# Change route in React Native with React Router after an async action

Tags: reactjs, react-native, redux, react-router, react-redux

I have a few routes setup like so:

```
import createHistory from 'history/createMemoryHistory';
import { NativeRouter, Route } from 'react-router-native';

<NativeRouter history={createHistory()}>
  <View style={styles.container}>
    <Route exact path='/' component={Home}/>
    <Route path='/page1' component={Page1}/>
  </View>
</NativeRouter>
```

Now it's simple to change routes programmatically in my `Home` class for example:

```
this.props.history.push('/page1');
```

But in the case of an async action that I'm dispatching with Redux:

```
export function login(email, password) {

    return function(dispatch) {

        dispatch(setAuthBusy(true));

        return auth.signIn(email, password)
        .then(function (user) {
            dispatch(setAuthBusy(false));
            dispatch(setUser(user));

            // !CHANGE ROUTE HERE!

        })
        .catch(function (err) {
            dispatch(setAuthBusy(false));
            dispatch(setAuthError(err.message));
        });
    };

}
```

In this case you can see that it's a login action that authenticates a user and only if the user has been successfully authenticated does the route change to `/page1` for instance.

I have a feeling that changing routes in your async actions isn't the correct way to go about it so I'd appreciate some advice in terms of the general architecture and flow of the app. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you start to deal with async actions, you should give a look at [redux-thunk](https://www.npmjs.com/package/redux-thunk) middleware.

Using `redux-thunk` you could do the following :

```
class Home extends React.Component {

  this.onLogin = () => {
    dispatch(login('toto', 'toto')).then(() => {
      this.props.history.push('/page1');
    })
  }

}
```

This mean that the route change in your case could be managed by the component itself.

Hope it help.

Comment: Thanks for the reply @Okazari , though I'm already using redux-thunk in my example above. Could you elaborate on your answer and be a bit more specific how I can change routes?

Comment: @Tiwaz89 Improved the example to fit your usecase, is this enought ?